# CiviDiscount Usage Limit Per Member

Tags: cividiscount

Is there any way to set a discount using CiviDiscount so that each member receives a use limit rather than a use limit for the disount itself? I am creating memberships whereby users pay for a group of events, usually five, they can then attend these events for free. But for this to work I need to limit the CiviDiscount at 5 uses per member.

Comment: I should add that I want the discount to be automatic, I don't want to have to create discount code for each user each time they buy a block of 5 events.

Comment: Yes, we need the same thing. I'm surprised this isn't already in CiviDiscount, as every discount module I use elsewhere includes this ability.